# setTimeout and clearTimeout as callback to hook programatically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a function that return setTimeout as a callback to call it programmatically and a clearTimeout as a callback to cancel the setTimeout before it executes the internal callback if necessary, is it possible?

```
function useDelay(cb: () => void, delay: number) {
  const timer = () => setTimeout(cb, delay);
  const clearTimer = () => clearTimeout(timer());
  return [timer, clearTimer];
}
```

Comment: Is this a hook for React?

Comment: Not necessarily, but can be too.

Comment: Something like this? (Sorry about formatting.)
function useDelay(cb: () => void, delay: number) {
  let id;
  const timer = () => {
    if (id) throw new Error('Timer already set');
    id = setTimeout(cb, delay);
  };
  const clearTimer = () => clearTimeout(id);
  return [timer, clearTimer];
}

Comment: @undefined-mind - sorry updated below

Answer (score -1):

You we're executing the timer in the clearTimeout. It should take a reference instead.

```js
function useDelay(cb = () => {}, delay = 2000) {
  let timerRef;
  const timer = () => {
    timerRef = setTimeout(cb, delay);
  }
  const clearTimer = () => clearTimeout(timerRef);
  return [timer, clearTimer];
}

const [timer, clearTimer] = useDelay(() => console.log('test'), 2000);
```